# Searchbar: Drop-down list. Looking for code or explanation

Tags: iphone

I want to implement a drop-down list object of available options during the typing.
As for now I have implemented this search elimination using UISearchBar and results appears at a UITableView. 
Instaed of this UITableView, I'd like that the list will drop-down from the searchbar like commonly done in other searchbars (like google search bar).
Any suggestions???
I'll be greatfull for real code or just some guidelines.
Thanks.
***Happy new YEAR.***

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard iPhone UIKit construct; you'll have to write your own class here, there's nothing really to base it on.